# Simplification of boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

Question 1
$$\begin{align*}A'BC + AB'C + ABC + A'B'C'
&=A'B C + B' C (A +A') + ABC\\
&=A'B + C + B'C + ABC 
\end{align*}$$

Question 2
$$\begin{align*}A'B + B'C + CB
&=A'B + C(B +B')\\
&=A'B + C 
\end{align*}$$

are these correct?

Comment: Q1 is wrong and Q2 is correct.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, you seem to have misread $A'B'C'$ as $A'B'C$; even then, your simplification is incomplete. Correct would be (using that $ABC + ABC = ABC$):

\begin{align}
A'BC + AB'C + ABC + A'B'C' &= (A'+A)BC + (B+B')AC + A'B'C'\\
&= BC + AC + A'B'C' \\
&= (A+B)C + A'B'C'
\end{align}

---

Question 2 is correct.